# How to download a page with wget but ignore 404 error messages if the page does not exist?

Tags: wget

Is there any way to have `wget` ignore HTTP error response codes when downloading a URL or spidering a webpage?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming I understood what you mean by "ignoring errors", you can try the `--content-on-error` argument. According to wget [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Content-On-Error), it will force wget to skip status error codes\.

Comment: But unfortunately don't work for all response codes. E.g. working on `404` but not on `401` (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393616/how-to-get-http-server-response-in-case-of-401-using-wget)).

Comment: For me this option works only for the HTML page itself, but wget still won't download images and other stuff with it

Comment: @joe you can use the wget options to pass basic authentication in your wget request. --user <username> --password <pw>