# How to make wget ignore errors instead of completely stop?

Tags: wget

I keep getting `wget` errors such as "`Bad file descriptor`" when trying to write to a filesystem that can't handle `!` in filenames.

Unfortunately this ends the whole job rather than moving onto the next file. How can I make `wget` ignore/skip any errors instead of quit completely?

(edit: seems I'm getting this error for files even without special characters but still the same issue with `wget` quitting half-way through a long job rather than continuing to the next file.)

Comment: Is it duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095741/how-to-download-a-page-with-wget-but-ignore-404-error-messages-if-the-page-does ?

Comment: Seems different to me. This isn't related to HTTP error responses.